# How to activate option menu when search box is displayed? (SearchManager)

Tags: android, search

I am trying to build a quick search box. it is basically a widget. Upon clicking, it pops up the quick search box and launch the browser with query string. No activity except searchactivity.

And also added codes for 'recent query suggestion' But having a problem to have menu for 'clear history' Here is what I wanted to implement. When quick search box is displayed, by pressing menu button, I want option menu to be popped up, keypad to be disappeared, quick search box to be stayed.

the implementation of google sample code - Searchable dictionary is not what I want to implement. It starts an activity with instruction message and when a user presses the search button or menu button, it pops up the quick search box. Mine is when it runs from a widget, the quick search box is popped up right away just like the google search widget.

How can I override onCreateOptionMenu on searchmanager? Or is there any way to activate option menu  when the searchmanager is activated?

Please take a look at the images below. the second image is what I want to implement upon clicking menu button.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is make the search button launch the default search activity when it is pressed.   And make it sorta match the existing search dialog style.  You can notice this is how the official Twitter client works.  You can use apktool (google it) to take a look at the official Twitter clients resource files to get a better idea of how this can be accomplished.

Comment: Thank you, schwiz, for you answer. So... you're saying that it is not actually using SearchManager, right?

Comment: you would still be using the SearchManager but you would override onSearchRequested to not drop down the default searchbox so you can replace it with your own.  More details here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#SearchableActivity

Comment: Thanks again. I guess there is no way just to add option menu without making my own search dialog.

Comment: What is this little icon (the computer) left of the edit text field called? So hard to search for that ...